# How to: Get instance of gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Looking to get an instance of this game object so I can successfully use .enabled to hide it in a scene.

```
PlayPortalLoginButton loginButton = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayPortalLoginButton>();
```

Fairly new to C# and I believe I am close to achieving my goal with the line above. What needs changed? Want to understand how to correctly do this.

Comment: the line above indicates you already have the gameobject.

Comment: @Eddge i have reference to the gameObject but i need to reference an instance of the gameObject above. Not the original gameObject

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here.  All MonoBehaviors have a reference to their GameObjects using the gameObject variable.  So, in this case, you are saying `GetComponent<T>()` using gameObject.  that components gameObject will be the same.  Now if you mean you want to get the MonoBehavior of PlayPortalLoginButton that is on another GameObject you would want to use FindObjectOfType, or even give this script a public reference to that object.

Comment: `GetComponent` Only gets the components of that type on this gameObject not components of that type on other objects in the scene.  Which is why you would use FindObjectOfType.

Comment: Or GameObject.Find or various combinations there of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you could find a component on a `GameObject` in the scene, where "PortalLoginButton" is the name of the `GameObject` as seen in the editor:

```cs
var loginButton = GameObject.Find("PortalLoginButton");
loginButton.enabled = false;
```

However, `GameObject.Find("...")` searches the name of every `GameObject` in the scene, and this is not usually the best way to reference a `GameObject` since it is not very efficient. *So make sure not to use `GameObject.Find("...")` or similar function calls in the `Update()` function because it will execute every frame and slow your game down*. If the `GameObject` is not instantiated while the game is running, it is usually better to make a global reference to any `GameObject` or `Component` that you use in your script and then drag-and-drop the `GameObject` with the `Component` you are looking for into the field in the editor. Alternatively, you can use `GameObject.Find("...")` in the `Start()` or `Awake()` functions to store a reference to the `GameObject` that you are looking for, so that the search only happens once at the start of your game.

Here is an example of how to store the reference in global field (it will show up in the editor and you can drag-and-drop the `GameObject` into it). The differences between using a public field vs a private field are explained in the comments (you can decide on using public or private):

```cs
// By default, private fields are not viewable in the editor,
// but the [SerializeField] attribute, placed before
// the field declaration, allows them to be visible.
[SerializeField]
private GameObject loginButtonPrivateReference;
// If you need to access loginButton from another script, 
// you can make it a public field.
// Public fields are viewable in the editor by default.
public GameObject loginButtonPublicReference;
```

Here is an example of how you can use GameObject.Find("...") in the `Awake()` function:

```cs
private GameObject loginButton;

private void Awake() {
    loginButton = GameObject.Find("PortalLoginButton");
}
```

---

If you need to search for `GameObjects` in your scene by type or by tag name, see the `GameObject` documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) for more information. Searching by type is less efficient and searching by tag is more efficient than searching by name because type searches check each component on each `GameObject`, and tag searches search only an organized `GameObject` subset.

Answer (score 0):

```
GameObject button;
void Start() {
    button = GameObject.Find ("yourButtom");
}
void SomeEvent() {
    button.SetActive(false);   
}
```

I think you have to help to you

Comment: This clones a prefab, the button likely already exists in the scene

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get access to a gameObject in a script depending on exactly which gameObject you are trying to get.

If you are trying to access a GameObject of a behavior in the behavior script then simply using `gameObject` should suffice since that is the gameObject that behavior is attached to.

Accessing a script that is attached to another GameObject is where it can be tricky.  For scenes such as a MainMenu, there is nothing wrong with giving it a public reference as an example:

```
public PlayPortalLoginButton loginButton;

void setLoginState(bool activate) {
    loginButton.enabled = activate;
}
```

With this example you would just drag and drop the gameObject with the PlayPortalLoginButton script on your manager script, the script that would control whether it is enabled or not.

If you need a more modular approach to it for example in a gameplay scene where you are populating objects at run time the approach you can take is:

```
PlayPortalLoginButton loginButton;

void setLoginState(bool activate) {
    if(loginButton == null)
    {
        loginButton = FindObjectOfType<PlayPortalLoginButton>();
    }
    // Requires the correct version of .net otherwise you can reuse the check above...
    loginButton?.enabled = activate;
}
```

In the above script if you needed to gameObject of loginButton, now you can access it through loginButton.gameObject.

There are some more examples you could use and other approaches however I feel the above should suffice if for a menu.

I will also mention I am avoiding example of `GameObject.Find` and `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`  as those are more prone to error.  They will only work if your name or tag are correctly marked, if you rename them for any reason then your scripts will fail to find the Object, and this can cause an issue with troubleshooting.

Using FindObjectOfType, you are less likely to have an error, and if you remove that script type these scripts will populate an error indicating the script no longer exists.  When refactoring, if you right click on the behaviors name and use the rename option it will automatically update references to the script throughout your code.